# Why one over another: UBound or Length

Tags: vb.net

Could there be any specific reason why one can choose `UBound` over `Length`?

Here is the code and 1-dimension is passed as second parameter.

```
    For iIndex = 0 To UBound(myList)
        If Left(Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR"), Len(myList(iIndex))) = saIPList(iIndex) Then
            bAuth = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Any performance gain against `Length`

Comment: And don't forget `myList.GetUpperBound()`

Comment: I am seeing this question has become a famous question as it got more than 10K view. It brings back memories when I was working for a company using Visual Basic. I don't even remember most of the Visual Basic code. Time flies.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They do different things! `UBound` gives you the last index in the array, while `Length` gives you the length. Those are not the same, because usually `UBound` will be `Length - 1`.

Comment: For 1-dimensional arrays, `UBound` will *always* be `Length - 1`, so they are not really different. For multi-dimensional arrays, they do quite different things.

Answer (score 4):

Ubound exists mainly for backwards compatibility to old code. I haven't seen anything saying it's deprecated just yet, but at the same time I recognize it's not really aligned with the way they have been taking the language in recent years.  The same is true for the Len() and Left() functions in that code; they are the way of the past, not the future. The sooner you adapt, the happier you will be.

For what it's worth, the argument is largely moot. More "modern" ways to write that code look *entirely* different. Here's one example:

```
bAuth = myList.Zip(saIPList, Function(a,b) New With {.Length = a.Length, .saIP = b} ) _
              .Any(Function(i) Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR").ToString().SubString(0,i.Length) = i.saIP)
```

Comment: I sincerely mean this will all due respect, but at least for me you just made simple code very hard to read at a glance with little or not benefit.

Comment: @Chris - perhaps this isn't the best example to illustrate clarity  because of the need for .Zip, but in the general case this style is better for clarity, correctness, and performance. We do see that here, as the original code is incorrect because of how it uses the index variable. This code is safe regardless of how many items the other array has.

Comment: yep, its the `Zip` that for me adds the unneeded complexity for me. I know you're working with what the OP gave you, too.

Comment: And for what its worth, I'm pretty sure this would work, too `bAuth = saIPList.Any(Function(s) s.StartsWith(Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")))`

Answer (score 4):

For performance gain I was also interested in what function has the best performance.

It seems that the length -1 is much faster than the UBound. I expected UBound to be faster somehow.

After 100.000.000 times it seems the time for length -1 is 952ms and for UBound: 5844ms.

**(length -1) is ~6 times faster than UBound**

Code used for testing

```
Private Sub UboundlengthToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UboundlengthToolStripMenuItem.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    ListBox1.Items.Add("BEGIN")

    'set required vars
    Dim ints() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    'end vars setting

    Dim t As New Stopwatch
    Dim gt As New Stopwatch
    Dim time1 As Integer
    Dim temp As Integer

    Dim d As Double = GC.GetTotalMemory(False)

    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    GC.Collect()
    GC.GetTotalMemory(False)

    ListBox1.Items.Add("Free Memory:   " & d)

    gt.Start()
    t.Reset()
    'starting test---------------------------------------

    'single test---------------------------------------
    t.Start()
    For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.Text
        temp = ints(ints.Length - 1)
    Next
    t.Stop()
    time1 = t.ElapsedMilliseconds
    ListBox1.Items.Add("arr.length - 1")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Func1 total time: " & time1)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Func1 single time: " & time1 / TextBox1.Text)
    t.Reset()
    'single test---------------------------------------

    'single test---------------------------------------
    t.Start()
    For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.Text
        temp = ints(UBound(ints))
    Next
    t.Stop()
    time1 = t.ElapsedMilliseconds
    ListBox1.Items.Add("UBound:")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Func1 total time: " & time1)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Func1 single time: " & time1 / TextBox1.Text)
    t.Reset()
    'single test---------------------------------------

    'Finishing test--------------------------------------
    gt.Stop()
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Total time " & gt.ElapsedMilliseconds)
    d = GC.GetTotalMemory(True) - d
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Total Memory Heap consuming (bytes)" & d)


    ListBox1.Items.Add("END")
End Sub
```

Tried different things to eliminate possible optimalisations of the compiler, all with the same result as stated above.

Answer (score 2):

It's carried over from earlier VB days.  UBound can give you the highest index of any single dimension in a multi-dimensional array.  Length only gives you the total number of elements.

If you declare:

```
' A 5x10 array:
Dim array(4, 9) As Integer
```

The values are:

```
array.Length = 50    ' Total number of elements.
array.Rank = 2       ' Total number of dimensions.
array.LBound(0) = 0  ' Minimum index of first dimension.
array.LBound(1) = 0  ' Minimum index of second dimension.
array.UBound(0) = 4  ' Maximum index of first dimension.
array.UBound(1) = 9  ' Maximum index of second dimension.
```

Comment: UBound and LBound are not methods of array, only functions where you supply the array as the first argument (and the rank or dimension as the second argument). 

So it would be UBound(array,1). There is however a method that corresponds to UBound (which UBound actually calls), and that is GetUpperBound, so e.g. array.GetUpperBound(1). Notice that there is no corresponding method for LBound, simply because in VB.NET the lower bound is always 0.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting UBounds is quite a bit faster in this example

```
  Dim startTick As Long

    For j As Integer = 1 To 5
        Dim rnd As New Random(Now.Subtract(Now.Date).TotalSeconds)
        Dim RandomMax As Integer = rnd.Next(10000, 100000)
        Dim cumbersome() As Integer = New Integer() {rnd.Next}

        'Ubound is better than Length.  Using Length takes as much time as redimensioning the entire array.
        startTick = Environment.TickCount
        For i As Integer = 1 To RandomMax - 1
            ReDim Preserve cumbersome(UBound(cumbersome) + 1)
            cumbersome(UBound(cumbersome)) = Rnd.Next
        Next
        Debug.Print("{0}) Array Method UBound: {1} Ticks to construct {2} integers", j, Environment.TickCount - startTick, RandomMax)


        'Length is slow don't use it
        startTick = Environment.TickCount
        For i As Integer = 1 To RandomMax - 1
            ReDim Preserve cumbersome(cumbersome.Length)
            cumbersome(cumbersome.Length - 1) = Rnd.Next
        Next
        Debug.Print("{0}) Array Method Length: {1} Ticks to construct {2} integers", j, Environment.TickCount - startTick, RandomMax)
    Next
```